# C++ Map with two keys of different values

Tags: c++, dictionary, key, multiple-definition-error

I need a map which can have two keys, of different data types, yet point to the same struct.

```
struct DataStruct {
   SomeEnum keyEnum;      // <---- key as enum
   std::string keyString;  // <----- a key as a string

   int arbitrarydata;
   int moredata;
}
```

Then I want a `std::map` I can look up like:

```
std::map<SomeEnum||std::string, DataStruct> dataMap; 
dataMap[SomeEnum::AValue] = dataStruct1; 
dataMap["mykey"] = dataStruct2;
```

Is this even possible or do I need to make 2 maps?  Seems a waste.  Or do I need to overload an operator or something?

Comment: Have you considered Boost's [multi-index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) container?

Comment: I will have to look into that it seems like a good solution generally although this is for an embedded system so not sure how much of boost I can drag into.

Comment: If you don't need the full functionality of Boost try wrapping your own.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::pair`, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <utility>

typedef enum {A, B, C} en;

int main ()
{
  en myen = A;
  std::map<std::pair<char,int>, int> mymap;

  mymap.insert ( std::pair<std::pair<char, int>,int>(std::make_pair('a',myen),200) );
  mymap.insert ( std::pair<std::pair<char, int>,int>(std::make_pair('z',30),400) );

  // showing contents:
  std::cout << "mymap contains:\n";
  for (std::map<std::pair<char,int>, int>::iterator it=mymap.begin(); it!=mymap.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << "(" << it->first.first << ", " << it->first.second <<
          ") => " << it->second << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Not an answer in the question:

Note, that in C++11, you can use `enum class`, which in general can be more useful.

Answer (score 1):

A `std::map` can only have keys of the same type, but you can trick it with whatever key logic you want. Just be sure that they can compare properly:

```
struct DataStruct {
  struct Key {
    std::string keyString;
    SomeEnum keyEnum;
    int type;
    Key(SomeEnum a) : keyEnum(a), type(0) { }
    Key(const char * a) : keyString(a), type(1) { }
    bool operator<(const Key & o) const { 
      if (type != o.type) return type < o.type;
      else return type == 0 ? keyEnum < o.keyEnum : keyString < o.keyString;
    }
  };
  int data;
}
```

Then you can use it almost the way you wanted:

```
std::map<DataStruct::Key, DataStruct> dataMap;
dataMap[SomeEnum::AValue] = dataStruct1; 
dataMap["mykey"] = dataStruct2;
```

You need to be sure that keys of different types don't point to the same data, thats why I first order them by type and then by their value.